# replace missing content with sed

Tags: sed

In a file i have this structure:

```
192.168.1.53 # hostname, city, state
192.168.1.101 # hostname, city, state
192.168.1.10 # hostname, city, state
192.168.1.18 # hostname, city, state
192.168.1.19 
192.168.1.104 # hostname, city, state
```

How can I use sed to find and replace when there is NOT a '#' but replace after ip then move on to next one that is missing '#'.

So it looks like below:

```
192.168.1.53 # hostname, city, state
192.168.1.101 # hostname, city, state
192.168.1.10 # hostname, city, state
192.168.1.18 # hostname, city, state
192.168.1.19 # newcontent, new, new
192.168.1.104 # hostname, city, state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the piece you want to add is a fixed string, it's pretty easy:

```
sed 's/^[^#]*$/& # newcontent, new, new/'
```

In the replacement string, `&` stands for the matched text.